OPOS Driver for Scale Developing. Can't correctly register dll (C#)
Here's my code:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using OPOSCONSTANTSLib;
using OposScale_CCO;

namespace ScaleOPOS
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("D3673432-393B-4CFF-B382-CED8F12F3388")]
    [ProgId("ScaleOPOS.WeightScale")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]

    public class WeightScale : IOPOSScale
    {
        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void DllRegisterServer(Type type)
        {
            try
            {
                string classKey = @"Software\Wow6432Node\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\Scale";
                using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(classKey + @"\EmulatedScale"))
                {
                    key.SetValue("FriendlyName", "WeightScale");
                    key.SetValue("ProgID", "ScaleOPOS.WeightScale");
                    key.SetValue("Version", "1.0");
                }

                // Запись для ProgID
                string progIdKey = @"Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\ScaleOPOS.WeightScale";
                using (RegistryKey progId = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(progIdKey))
                {
                    progId.SetValue("", "WeightScale");
                    progId.SetValue("CLSID", type.GUID.ToString("B").ToUpper());
                }

                // Запись для CLSID
                string clsidKey = $@"Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{type.GUID.ToString("B").ToUpper()}";
                using (RegistryKey clsid = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(clsidKey))
                {
                    clsid.SetValue("", "WeightScale"); // Имя вашего COM-объекта

                    using (RegistryKey inprocServer = clsid.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32"))
                    {
                        inprocServer.SetValue("", @"C:\Users\Dmitriy\Desktop\ScaleOPOSDriver\bin\Debug\ScaleOPOSDriver.dll"); // Укажите путь к вашей DLL
                        inprocServer.SetValue("ThreadingModel", "Apartment");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Ошибка регистрации: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void DllUnregisterServer(Type type)
        {
            try
            {
                string classKey = @"Software\Wow6432Node\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\Scale";
                Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(classKey + "\\EmulatedScale", false);

                string progIdKey = @"Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\ScaleOPOS.WeightScale";
                Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(progIdKey, false);

                string clsidKey = $@"Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{type.GUID.ToString("B").ToUpper()}";
                Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(clsidKey, false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Здесь можно записать лог или вывести сообщение об ошибке
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Ошибка регистрации: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }


        public WeightScale() { }

        public void SOData(int Status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SODirectIO(int EventNumber, ref int pData, ref string pString)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SOError(int ResultCode, int ResultCodeExtended, int ErrorLocus, ref int pErrorResponse)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SOOutputCompleteDummy(int OutputID)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SOStatusUpdate(int Data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int SOProcessID()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int CheckHealth(int Level)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ClaimDevice(int Timeout)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ClearInput()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Close()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int DirectIO(int Command, ref int pData, ref string pString)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Open(string DeviceName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ReleaseDevice()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ReadWeight(out int pWeightData, int Timeout)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int DisplayText(string Data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ZeroScale()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ResetStatistics(string StatisticsBuffer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int RetrieveStatistics(ref string pStatisticsBuffer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int UpdateStatistics(string StatisticsBuffer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int CompareFirmwareVersion(string FirmwareFileName, out int pResult)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int UpdateFirmware(string FirmwareFileName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int OpenResult => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string CheckHealthText => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool Claimed => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool DeviceEnabled { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public bool FreezeEvents { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public int ResultCode => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int ResultCodeExtended => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int State => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string ControlObjectDescription => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int ControlObjectVersion => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string ServiceObjectDescription => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int ServiceObjectVersion => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string DeviceDescription => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string DeviceName => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int MaximumWeight => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int WeightUnit => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int WeightUnits => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int BinaryConversion { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public bool CapDisplay => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool AutoDisable { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public int CapPowerReporting => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int DataCount => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool DataEventEnabled { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public int PowerNotify { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public int PowerState => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool AsyncMode { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public bool CapDisplayText => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapPriceCalculating => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapTareWeight => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapZeroScale => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int MaxDisplayTextChars => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public decimal SalesPrice => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int TareWeight { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public bool CapStatisticsReporting => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapUpdateStatistics => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapCompareFirmwareVersion => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapUpdateFirmware => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool CapStatusUpdate => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int ScaleLiveWeight => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int StatusNotify { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public bool ZeroValid { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}

.NET FRAMEWORK 4.8
Regasm name.dll /codebase  command works successfully. And third-party OPOS tester show my driver in its list. But choosing my driver I get (loot at pic.below):
enter image description here
What I do wrong? I heard there's no need to tell excplicitly paths in registry or is need? Please, help!!
I tried not to show paths explicitly, but in this way OPOS test doesn't see my driver at all.
I tried to register dll with regsvr32. In this way I get "entry point to DllRegisterServer not found!"
Sorry for my English))

It smells like you register in the 64-bit registry (running regasm from Framework64) and the client runs from a 32-bit process (so accesses the 32-bit registry), or the reverse (you register in the 32-bit registry (running regasm from Framework) and the client runs from a 64-bit process (so accesses the 64-bit registry).

No. I tried each way. Tell me, please. do I must write paths or parameters like comvisible, progid, guid before class is enough?

"class not registered" is a precise error that means the client doesn't find the classID it's expecting in the registry it's reading from. It can be a wrong classId, the wrong registry (32 vs 64) and that's usually it (after that, when the class is found, you can face other issues). You can diagnose the registry accesses using a tool such as procmon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon filter by registry access and your client's process name.

The answer in this article may be helpful. How to create a OPOS Service Object virtual printer - c# [closed]

Now I changed my code. The string opos_reg = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\Scale\WeightScale" is only key  to be hardcoded. The left keys are registered by regasm. I erased 'em from code. And due to harcoded string in my code OpodDriverTest can see my driver, but I can't call any method. Error: OPOS_E_NOSERVICE. Looking into logs I can see a creating instance of class in dll on every button click in tester, but calling any method causes failure. To tell the truth I haven't seen @kunif answer yes. Right now I'll do it

@kunif, I've read and installed pos for .net, I have installed OPOSCCO much eaarlier, and then what? I don't understand. In VS I can't find installedd pos for .net in references or I must not find it? In additional, sorry for repeat, I can connect with dll in VS and call its method while straight connection, not COM. And when COM in OPOSDriverTest I can only create instance and cannot invoke methods

Are you using VS2022? VS2022 IDE and tools should run in 64-bit. Currently, OPOS-CCO up to 1.14.001 only supports 32-bit mode. Why not try migrating to VS2019 or VS2017 and building and debugging?

Ok, but but why my code has success in build if vs2022 64bit and OPOS_CCO in 32 bit. Moveover, target architecture is set to x86. I'll try your advice but it's a lil weird I think

The build will be successful because 32-bit/64-bit mode is specified. However, the IDE, designer, debugger, etc. basically run in 64-bit and refer to the 64-bit registry when doing so, so if you try to simply use a dll without any ingenuity it will fail because the 32-bit/64-bit modes are different. By the way, here is another article that is not related to me that you may find useful: Implementing an OPOS printer service object for capturing printed text, Implement OPOS Device in C#
